# Problem with intersects operator in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry

I have this table below

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_polyline_volume (
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null );
```

I am trying to make this query:

```
SELECT id 
    FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume 
    WHERE box'((15,47),(16,48))' ?# coordinates;
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: box ?# path
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I find if a path is intersecting with a box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Postgres' geometric types, but it looks like the `?#` operator doesn't allow direct comparisons between `box` and `path` values, and there don't seem to be any automatic casts to help with this.

However, you can explicitly convert the `box` to a `polygon`, then convert the `polygon` to a `path`, which you can check for intersections with another `path`:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume 
  WHERE path(polygon(box'((15,47),(16,48))')) ?# coordinates;
```

---

For reference, you can check the supported input types for an operator using:

```
select oprleft::regtype::text, oprright::regtype::text
from pg_operator
where oprname = '?#'
```

... and the functions to convert between geometric types are listed in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE).

Comment: Thanks it was very helful

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with the query above:

```
SELECT *   FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume    WHERE path(polygon(box'((15,47),(16,48))')) ?# popen(coordinates) or polygon(box'((15,47),(16,48))') @> polygon(coordinates);
```